# Accumulating Materialized Views In Cassandra.

Tags: cassandra

Hi as I am new to Cassandra I am reading some books, docs, and blog posts to get myself familiar with it.
Now I would like to get some answer to how to implement  "Accumulating Materialized Views In Cassandra" and by that I mean : 
Suppose that we have the following model 
Game { userId, gameName, time,gameMoney .... , etc. } If I want to "Aggregate" games by userId, gameName, I will need denormalize the table to some Materialized View, where the same data is stored but in different model.

What I want is when some record is inserted into the first table a record is inserted in the materialized view or it is update and accumulated if exist.

For example :

```
Game { 1,gameOne,12:00,1.2}  
Game {1, gameTwo, 12:00, 2.3} 
Game {1,gameTwo,11:00, 2.3}
```

In the denormalized Materialized View, I want to have two record ( an aggregation by userId and game name) that will look like

```
UserGames { 1,gameOne,1.2 } 
UserGames {1,gameTow, 4.6 }
```

I know about triggers but curious if there are some other ways to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 5):

Aggregating materialized views are still not implemented. Here is the relevant [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9778) and a [video explaining](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmsQNNdDuSA) how the feature would look like.

Depending on how much data you'll have, you could consider using [aggregates](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateAggregate.html).